# How to find the controller/action which maps to an attribute route?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, controller, attributerouting

Given a URL, and I want to know which action in which controller is responsible for handling that URL. What I do right now is that I search for the route name in the project from visual studio. But I think there might be a package or tool that lists the routes and their corresponding Controller actions.

Is there a more neat way to find that:

```
url/examples/1
```

is handled by:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("examples/{id}")]
public Task viewExmaple()
```

Comment: not at the moment all you can do is do a project level find function in your visual studio

Comment: Does https://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger help?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Swagger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger), as I think this will be as close as you can get in terms of "lists the routes and their corresponding Controller actions". By default, swagger acts a GUI (web page) that displays every controller with corresponding controller methods nested beneath(accordion style). 
Swagger is also a great tool for debugging and testing. It displays details like which HTTP verb the methods use, which query string params (or JSON payload in body) the method accepts. Great for documentation as well.
Behind the scenes, swagger builds one giant JSON payload that nests all of your controller / controller actions so you may also be able to view it like that.

You would access it by hitting http(s)://your.app.path/swagger

[Setting up in a .NET Standard (Non-Core) app](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-development/visual-studio-2017-swagger-building-documenting-web-apis/)